# Binding in Code doesn't react to source object changing

Tags: wpf, binding, datacontext, code-behind

I have a dependency property on a class inheriting from adorner, like so:

```
public class LoadingAdorner : Adorner
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof (string), typeof (LoadingAdorner), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsShowingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsShowing", typeof (bool), typeof (LoadingAdorner), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool)));

    ...
}
```

Adorner's don't really have any XAML, but I wanted the text of this adorner to be bindable to the viewmodel.  So I create the binding in code, in the view's constructor, like so:

```
    private readonly LoadingAdorner _loading;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _loading = new LoadingAdorner(MainPage);
        var bind = new Binding("LoadingText"){Source = DataContext};
        _loading.SetBinding(LoadingAdorner.TextProperty, bind);
    }
```

The DataContext is my view model, my view model implements INotifyPropertyChanged, LoadingText is a string property that calls OnPropertyChanged, etc.  All bindings in XAML work fine, however, the code binding does not.

I believe it is because at the time of creating the binding, the view model has not yet been set to the DataContext (it is null), I do this on the line after creating the view.  If I set this binding to a property on my view using Source = this, it works.

My question is, why are the XAML bindings are capable of reacting to the source object changing, while the code binding doesn't appear to be?  Is there a proper way for me to create a binding that will react to this similiar to the XAML bindings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding do not and **cannot** react to source changes, it is a logical impossibility, objects do not *change* properties and references *to objects* change. Bindings can react to `DataContext` property changes but only if you do *not* do something horrible like `Source = DataContext` which kills the mechanism by getting the current data context *once only*. Just drop that so the `DataContext` is the default source again and the binding should react to the changes.

If the `DataContext` is on another object than the one that is bound it needs to be moved into the `Path`, i.e. `new Binding("DataContext.LoadingText"){ Source = this }`.

Comment: new Binding("DataContext.LoadingText"){ Source = this } worked! Thank you! I am still not sure why omitting the Source and simply specifying the path as LoadingText isn't working, however.  I had the same thought - omit the source and it will default to DataContext...

Comment: @BrentYates: Well, it will bind to the `DataContext` *of the object object containing the bound property*, which in your case seems to be different from the `DataContext` of the `MainWindow`, so you need to set the source to the `MainWindow` to target its `DataContext` instead.